# Angular interpolation not updating

Tags: javascript, angular

I am writing again on my Angular 6 app, but todays I saw that the component (or the interpolation) is not updated when the value changed.
Here's the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TempsService, Temps } from '../../temps.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-temps',
  templateUrl: './temps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./temps.component.scss']
})
export class TempsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() solar: boolean;
  solarNum: number = 0;
  waterNum: number = 1;
  tempSolar: number = 2;
  tempWater: number = 10;
  timestamp: string;

  temps: Temps;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  showTemps() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(({ temps }) => {
      this.temps = temps;
    });
    this.tempSolar = this.temps[this.solarNum].rawValue;
    this.tempWater = this.temps[this.waterNum].rawValue;
    //this.timestamp = this.temps[this.solarNum].time;
  }/*

  updateTemps() {
    this.tempSolar = 5;
    this.tempService.channel.bind('data-update-event', function(data) {
      console.log('number: ' + data[0]);
      this.tempSolar = data[0];
      this.tempWater = data[1].rawValue;
    });
  }*/

  ngOnInit() {
   // this.showTemps();
   setInterval(this.showTemps(), 2000);
  }
}
```

If anybody has an idea, I would appreciate it a lot. Btw the "template" I am using is the NowUI on by CreativeTim.

Comment: Because you need to update your component variables inside the subscribe part only, not outside.

Comment: can i know why you are doing  setInterval(this.showTemps(), 2000);

Comment: I did this to see if the values get updated if it does another method call. I did put the variables into the subscribe method now but it doesn't work that way either.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker/stackblitz? Are you sure you are sending the data from the route?

Comment: The project is to big for stackblitz (at least it doesn't let me import it) and plunker is not a option right now as I have to copy over everything manually. The link for the repo would be: https://github.com/Tomson124/ResolVbus-Dashboard/tree/now-ui If I have some spare time later I could try making a stackblitz with just the things that are the problem right now.

Comment: The problem is not getting the data. It is send in through the service (and resolver/route) but I cannot get to update it once the site/app is loaded. Do I have to do the call for a second request from the database again in the service or just call the service/route again in the component?

Comment: it could be my plain overlooking at your resolvers and modules, but i could not find TempResolver in any providers array. Check if you are getting any console errors also, could you put a log in your service method to see if service is really getting called

Comment: Well the service is getting called as the initial variables are shown. But after that I don't know where to do a recall of the function, something has to trigger a new request from the server but I don't know where this hs to happen. The TempResolver is in no provider as it is done with "provideIn" in the resolver itself (new feature in Angular 6)